# generating function for a power sequence

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

The question is short:
I don't understand how should I solve this. Problem wants the G(x) of this:
1,4,9,16,...
I can solve this one but I cannot connect these two to each other:
1,2,3,4,...

Comment: If $G(x)$ is the generating function and of the form $G(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2} + \cdots$ then for the coefficients being $\{ 1, 4, 9, 16, \cdots\}$, which are squares, ie $\{1^{2}, 2^{2}, 3^{2}, \cdots \}$, then calculate $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{2} x^{n} $$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since you didn’t mention $0$, you apparently want

$$G(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)^2x^n\;.$$

Start with

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n$$

and differentiate with respect to $x$ to get

$$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)x^n\;.$$

Now multiply both sides by $x$ and ...

(If you actually want $\sum_{n\ge 0}n^2x^n$, some minor adjustment is necessary, but the same idea works.)